# Wrong scale on iphone 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I want test my new created app on my iPhone 5. Everytime I build it on my phone, it will have in the top and bottom a black bar. How can I remove that?

Comment: Could you please add more information around your problem and the steps you took to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add launch images to your project in all needed sizes!

Comment: Or use a launch storyboard